# activity name changes when i change app name

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

this problem is confusing me and i can't see where the issue is. when i change my app  name and icon  my launch activity name and icon (the one that shows at the top left screen) changes to that name and icon. But when i check the xml file of the launch activity it shows me otherwise.

**App name :** online shop

**Activity name :** Anmeldung

here is the Graphical layout in eclipse of the activity and that's how it supose  to be :

[image]

**and here is the activity in the emulator :**

[image]

**Androidmanifest.xml :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dbreader"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_login"
    android:label="@string/activity_login"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hochschule.main.Login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hochschule.main.Registrieren"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_registrieren"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registrieren" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hochschule.main.Shop"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_shop" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hochschule.main.WarenKorb"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_warenkorb"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_waren_korb" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you able to solve your problem?

Comment: yes it did ! sorry for the late response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android label tag is used for both **Default Title bar** and **App Name** in Home Screen

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

It may conflict with activity's label name sometimes. You can apply the programmatic method as alternative which surely works.

If you want to set **Activity** to your desired name in onCreate() in your activity as below:

```
this.setTitle("Your Title");
```

To set Icon:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.Your_Icon);
```

If you are using the support library to add the actionbar (ex: ToolBar), use getSupportActionBar instead of getActionBar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you ! but that only solves a part of the problem ! still can't change the icon of the activity ! how can i change it !!

Comment: @tahsinRupam *it is always safe to set it programmatically than in manifest* what is your claim based on? Its nonsense

Comment: @TimCastelijns He is already using two different strings for application label and activity label, He gets different label in preview. But not in emulator. That's why I suggested him to do it in activity class. Have I done terrible ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam the method setIcon is undefined for the type Login (Login is the name of my java class) is there any alternative ?